# How to fix "DOM UNABLE TO LOAD" error of vqmod in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to add a new submenu under the catalog in the admin of the opencart using Vqmod. Here is my code:

```
<modification>
<id>add menu</id>
<author>XXX</author>
<version>2.3</version>
<vqmver>1.0.8</vqmver>
    <!-- OPTION CONTROLLER -->  
    <file name="admin/controller/common/header.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            $this->data['text_newmenu'] = $this->language->get('text_newmenu');
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            $this->data['text_newmenu'] = $this->language->get('text_newmenu');
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            $this->data['doctor'] = $this->url->link('catalog/doctor', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            $this->data['newmenu'] = $this->url->link('catalog/newmenu', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <!-- OPTION LANGUAGE -->
    <file name="admin/language/english/common/header.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            $_['text_zone']  = 'Zones';
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            $_['entry_newmenu']  = 'Wow sexy';
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file> 
    <!-- header.tpl for new menu-->
    <file name="admin/view/template/common/header.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            <li><a href="<?php echo $doctor; ?>"><?php echo $text_doctor; ?></a></li>
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <li><a href="<?php echo $newmenu; ?>"><?php echo $text_newmenu; ?></a></li>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
<modification>
```

But there is an error comes in DOM UNABLE TO LOAD: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/work/oc/vqmod/xml/addmenu.xml` 
Does any one know whats the problem in my code?

Answer (score 2):

I Was facing the similar problem. I had given the permission to the file. But still it was saying unable to load. After little research i found that it had admin permission and no read permission from others, which can be given by :

```
sudo chmod a+r filename
```

if you want to give to entire directory, then

```
sudo chmod -R a+r directory/
```

and this fixed my bug..

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

addmenu.xml please validate this xml using an xml validator like this

http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

The error is because xml file is not a valid one

If this doesn't solve the problem , then try adding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

at top of the xml

Comment: I found the error in the xml file in last line i dont close the <modification> tab ...:)

Comment: @user1640432 then how u said previously that u validated that xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any non-standard characters in your `author` tag such as `á` `é` `í` `ó` `ú`? If so, make sure you put them in CDATA tags as well as putting the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

header at the very start of the document (with absolutely nothing before it)